# updating or insert values

Tags: mysql

I have created a table with :

```
$this->db->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `'.DB_PREFIX.'ct_forum_settings` (
`admin_online` int(1) NOT NULL default \'0\'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
');
```

And i am trying to when the user logs in insert or update if the row doesnt exist a value of 1 or 0 if the user has logged out.

login

```
@mysql_query ("REPLACE INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "ct_forum_settings (admin_online) VALUES(1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE admin_online='1'");
```

logout

```
@mysql_query ("REPLACE INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "ct_forum_settings (admin_online) VALUES(0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE admin_online='0'");
```

My only problem is i have tried insert into and replace into but they just keep creating rows of 1's and 0's i only need to update the row if it doesnt exist .

Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `REPLACE` or for `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` you need to give your table a unique key (usually the Primary Key is what u need).
Once u have that, and u will use the same value for the user (say, call the field `id` and make it `auto increment`) it will work

```
$this->db->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `'.DB_PREFIX.'ct_forum_settings` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`admin_online` int(1) NOT NULL default \'0\'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
');
```

if u have only one entry, no need for autoincrement, but then u will have to manually set the id.

Comment: yep, if u have only one entry, no need for autoincrement

Answer (score 0):

you can try to change REPLACE INTO

for inserting :

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `file_name`, `directory`) VALUES (NULL, '$filename', '$directory')");
```

for updateing :

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `file_name` = '$filename', `directory` = '$directory' WHERE `id` = id")
```